# Android - RSS - How can I get RSS of this link http://vtc.vn/RssCate.aspx?Group=0

Tags: android, rss

I want to get rss of this link

```
http://vtc.vn/RssCate.aspx?Group=0
```

how can I do that?
I use DOM parser, but it's not work
Please help me!
Thanks and best regard

Comment: Post you code here that you try and also post the error that give to parse this service.

Comment: What do you mean by rss of the link? Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html